# How come there is 4px of extra padding appearing under my <a> element?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, padding

H3LLO,

For some reason there is 4px of extra padding appearing under the **a** element. I am seeing this manifest in both Firefox and Chrome. I remember seeing this phenomenon on Flickr in its early days except it was a blue bar that appeared under s wrapped in  elements.

Here is a [link to the example code](http://jsbin.com/okadi3) that illustrates my problem. The background: of **a** has been colored red and the border: of **img** has been colored gray. As you can see, the **a** element is extending around 4px below the **img**.

To see the code just press the "***Edit using JSBIN***" link that appears at the top right corner when you hover over the window.

Any ideas on how to get rid of **a** element's extra bottom padding?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 46, accepted):

add          `vertical-align:bottom;`  to your img css properties.

Comment: Yes. Images are not on the same baseline as text.

Comment: thanks @pixeline. it worked. @Rob so images always hover over the baseline by default?

Comment: @pylonicon baseline is default for all elements

Answer (score 9):

```
a {display: inline-block}
img {display: block}
```

Images are rendered inline by default and you need to add `display: block` or `vertical-align: bottom` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only working way for me is to "remove" the margin is wrapping the image with div and set the size of div exactly the same as the image.

```
<div style="width:64px; height:64px">
  <img src ='image.png' style="width:64px; height:64px" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set to tag  "display: flex": a {display: flex}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I'm not positive why it occurs, but you could try [YUI Reset](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) to fix it.

Comment: is it best practice to include the YUI Reset at the beginning of all my CSS files?

Comment: I believe it's better to link the YUI Reset seperately, before you link your own CSS file(s)